# PackageManager: Not granting permission

Tags: android, permissions

Im trying to force my phone to go to sleep as soon as i turn my screen off, but whenever i install with adb, packagemanager informs me that it wont grant the permission i need, so my service throws an exception.  I was able to install another app called power save mode toggle which has the same permission, and it seems to work, so i should be able to get this to work, right?

Comment: Which permissions have you given to your app?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which permissions you did grant, or the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure you placed them in the correct area, try granting these:

[DEVICE_POWER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DEVICE_POWER)

[MODIFY_PHONE_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)

Comment: Why the downvote? No comment? These two permissions may be directly related to the OP's issue....